# Sorting nested array in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, nested, pymongo

I have following structure in mongodb collection as shown in the attached image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk3DZ.png)

I will have an index number and inside that, I will have records, now records will be an array or arrays as shown above.
I want to sort the data inside the records per score in Math subject.
What is the best way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can using `unwind` aggregate

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
       {
          $unwind:{
             path: "$Records",
             includeArrayIndex:"firstUnwind"
         }
       },
       {
          $unwind:{
             path: "$Records",
         }
       },
      { $sort : { Match: -1} },
      {
          $group: {
             _id: {
                id: "$_id",
                firstUnwind: "firstUnwind"
             },
             Index_Number: {$first: "$Index_Number"},
             Records: {$push: "$Records"}
          }
      },
      {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.id",
             Index_Number: {$first: "$Index_Number"},
             Records: {$push: "$Records"}
          }
      }
    ])`
```